# When clicked on button, go to the next question by ID

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building an online survey with statements in php. I retrieve my 2 statements per question via a database.

It should display question by question. So when you click at a statement, it saves the answer and inserts it into a table in the database with the value 0 or 1.

```
<?php
// I check if it's clicked, then it gets a '0' or a '1'. 
if(isset($_GET['manipulate'])){
        echo $_GET['manipulate'];
}
foreach($statements as $statement){ // "SELECT * FROM statement;" = $statements
        $datas_key[] = ["order"=>$statement["order"], "statement1"=> $statement["statement1"], "statement2"=> $statement["statement2"], "questionnaire_id"=> $statement["questionnaire_id"]];
}
?>
```

Now I have the 2 options which each a statement that can be clicked like this:

```
    <h1 id="newQ"> <?php $i = 0; ?></h1>
    <form method="GET">
    <h1>Question <?php echo $i + 1; ?> <br>
        <button class="manipulate" name="manipulate" value="0"><?php echo $datas_key[$i]["statement1"]; ?></button>
        <button class="manipulate" name="manipulate" value="1"><?php echo $datas_key[$i]["statement2"]; ?></button>
    </form>
```

How do i write code in js or php to make sure that when I click, the id goes +1 AND see the next question with the next two statements ??

Comment: in the if isset?? it doesn't overwrite the "<h1 id="newQ"> <?php $i = 0; ?></h1>" ..

Comment: `<h1>Question <?php echo $i + 1; ?> <br>` -> `<h1>Question <?php echo $i; $i++; ?> <br>`

Comment: this $i + 1 is just because the id starts at 0, so that was just to print "Question 1" (not question 0)

Comment: still not working

Comment: `$i++` adds 1 to `$i` every time you call it. it's meant to change the question number on every page. `Echo` doesn't store data in a variable, just outputs what you write. That way, you always have `$i = 1`. But if you write `echo $i; $i++;` you get your question number AND already add 1 to `$i` for the next question. I would recomment you to start `$i` with 1.