# When clicked on button, go to the next question from database by ID

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building an online survey with statements in php. I retrieve my 2 statements per question via a database.

It should display question by question. So when you click at a statement, it saves the answer and inserts it into a table in the database with the value 0 or 1.

```
<?php
$i = 0; 
// I check if it's clicked, then it gets a '0' or a '1' 
respectively for statement 1 or statement 2. 
if(isset($_GET['manipulate'])){
        echo $_GET['manipulate'];
        $answer = $_GET['manipulate'];
        Questions::set_answer($answer);
        $i++;


}
foreach($statements as $statement){ // "SELECT * FROM statement;" = $statements
        $datas_key[] = ["order"=>$statement["order"], "statement1"=> $statement["statement1"], "statement2"=> $statement["statement2"], "questionnaire_id"=> $statement["questionnaire_id"]];
}
?>
```

Now I have the 2 options which each a statement that can be clicked like this:

```
    <form method="GET">
    <h1>Question <?php echo $i + 1; ?> <br>
        <button class="manipulate" name="manipulate" value="0"><?php echo $datas_key[$i]["statement1"]; ?></button>
        <button class="manipulate" name="manipulate" value="1"><?php echo $datas_key[$i]["statement2"]; ?></button>
    </form>
```

How do i write code in js or php to make sure that when I CLICK ON OF THESE BUTTONS, the id goes +1 AND see the next question with the next two statements ?? this method is not working.
with the GET? with JS? 
Help me out

Comment: You asked the same thing not three hours ago already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073115/ Please do not create such duplicates, especially not after such a short time!

Comment: Yes i changed some things, so that it's more clear. This way I'm hoping to get an answer.